# Installing g++-multilib on MacOs

Tags: c++, macos, installation, g++

Is there a way to install g++-multilib on MacOs? I am searching the analog for the Ubuntu's command `sudo apt-get install g++-multilib` or `sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib`. Something like `brew install g++-multilib`.

**Thanks in advance!!**

Comment: Considering multilib is a way of cross compiling for different processor architectures, is using `lipo` an option for you?

Comment: @AhiyaHiya unfortunately, I was obliged to use multilib

Comment: Are you working on a project, made on Linux, that is being ported to macOS?

Comment: No, @AhiyaHiya, I am just trying to run C code where one function is implemented in assembly. In order to link `.asm` to `.c` without errors, I was said to use g++-multilib.